# opencv find perimeter of a connected component

Tags: c++, opencv, connected-components

I'm using opencv 2.4.13

I'm trying to find the perimeter of a connected component, I was thinking of using [ConnectedComponentWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241) but it doesn't return the perimeter, only the area, width, etc...
There is a method to find the area with the contour but not the opposite (with one component i mean, not the entire image).

The method [arcLength](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) doesn't work as well beause i have all the points of the component, not only the contour.

I know there is a BF way to find it by iterating through each pixel of the component and see if he has neighbors which aren't in the same component. But I'd like a function which costs less.
Otherwise, if you know a way to link a component with the contours found by the method findContours, it suits me as well.

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between a contour and a connected component, can you upload your input image?

Comment: The connected component has also the pixels inside the contour no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to use `findContours`.

You can compute the contour on the i-th component computed by `connectedComponents(WithStats)` , so they are *aligned* with your labels. Using `CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` you'll get all the points in the contour, so the `size()` of the vector is already a measure of the perimeter. You can eventually use `arcLength(...)` to get a more accurate result:

```
Mat1i labels;
int n_labels = connectedComponents(img, labels);

for (int i = 1; i < n_labels; ++i)
{
    // Get the mask for the i-th contour
    Mat1b mask_i = labels == i;

    // Compute the contour
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;     
    findContours(mask_i.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    if (!contours.empty())
    {
        // The first contour (and probably the only one)
        // is the one you're looking for

        // Compute the perimeter
        double perimeter_i = contours[0].size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i didn't know i could use findContours on a specific component with a mask, thank you !

Comment: Question : why did you use mask_i.clone() ? Isn't mask_i enough ?

Comment: FindContours will corrupt the input image. If you don't need the mask later, you can avoid the clone()

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Miki's answer, This is a faster way to find the perimeter of the connected component

```
//getting the connected components with statistics
cv::Mat1i labels, stats;
cv::Mat centroids;

int lab = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labels, stats, centroids);

for (int i = 1; i < lab; ++i)
{
    //Rectangle around the connected component
    cv::Rect rect(stats(i, 0), stats(i, 1), stats(i, 2), stats(i, 3));

    // Get the mask for the i-th contour
    Mat1b mask_i = labels(rect) == i;

    // Compute the contour
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;     
    findContours(mask_i, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    if(contours.size() <= 0)
         continue;        

    //Finding the perimeter
    double perimeter = contours[0].size();
    //you can use this as well for measuring perimeter
    //double perimeter = arcLength(contours[0], true);

}
```