# Calculating perimeter of an organic shape

Tags: python, image-processing

I have used Python to calculate areas or irregular shapes on black and white images by multiplying the number of white pixels by the area of an individual pixel.

However, now I also need to calculate the perimeter of this irregular shape. The shape may have holes in it. Here is an example image:

[image: Sample Image]

Any ideas how I can go about solving this problem?
I am not a complete newbie but I am not a coder either. Experienced beginner I guess.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
There are some things I still don't understand but this worked for me:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



def import_image(filename):
    original_image = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return original_image

#getting original file
img = import_image('PerimeterImage.jpg')

#converting to gray
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#set a thresh
thresh = 1

#get threshold image
ret,thresh_img = cv2.threshold(img_grey, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#find contours
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create an empty image for contours
img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)

perimeter = 0

for c in contours:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.0001 * peri, True)
    cv2.drawContours(img_contours, [approx], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    perimeter = perimeter + peri

print(f'Perimeter = {int(round(perimeter,0))} pixels')

#show image
cv2.imshow('Output', img_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#save image
cv2.imwrite('contours.jpg', img_contours)
```

Comment: Have a look at **OpenCV** `findContours()`... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746356/2836621 and here https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: See [my blog post on the subject](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/310). It contains MATLAB code, but at least should inform you enough to avoid solutions like in the answer below.

Comment: Thanks, the last method suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`cv.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga95f5b48d01abc7c2e0732db24689837b) to find the contours of the white area, generally, you will have to do threshold before `findContours`, but since your image is black and white maybe you can ignore it.

For perimeter just use [`cv.arcLength`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) for the contour you want.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

I have included two very similar approaches. Both approaches use opencv library and its magic. The second one is mainly there if you are interested in the simplified version of how this can be done.

**Method 1** (preferred)

I think this would be the easiest option for you.

```py
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('img.jpg', 0) #Get your image
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
```

Then you can count the pixels to get the perimeter.

More info about this can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).

---

**Method 2**

1. First, use Laplacian to get the image gradient magnitude.

```
laplacian = cv.Laplacian(img, cv.CV_64F)
```

2. Then, you can either move to step 3 or do this for more accurate results. Use non-maximum suppression to make the edges 1 pixel thin. This is not easy, but you can find an explanation of the idea behind this at the canny link above.
3. Count the remaining pixels to get the perimeter.

You should know that this will be imperfect as things such as black spots inside your objects will also be counted. If you do not want
that, you can do a closing operation before the non-maximum suppression using:

```
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

---

**Note:** These solutions suppose that your input images will always be like the one you provided. If they are not, then some changes will have to be made.

Comment: 1: Counting pixels along the contour heavily underestimates the perimeter length. 2: Canny and Laplacian zero crossings are both methods to find edges in gray-value images. The image in the OP is binary, there is no need to do anything complicated to find the perimeter.